# "How to make an entire Game X" - off-topic?

Tags: discussion, topical

For instance, [**How to make a Battleship game?**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2364/how-to-make-a-battleships-game)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes.

If this comment gets more than 5 votes I'm going to close it (if the community and/or another mod doesn't do it first).

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for [not a real question] *...cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.*

Comment: Sounds good to me.  The question already has -4 so keeping it open any longer is probably not worth it.  I'm surprised there are no community close votes, though.

Comment: I'd have voted to close, but alas, don't yet have the 500 points needed. :) Just for the record, only 23/1,540 people (1.5%) do have enough rep.