# handling "feature like game X"

Tags: discussion

I have been seeing some questions that refer to some `gameX`. in some cases I have heard of, or even played the game in others I have not, and I feel the OP does not explain what the feature is, or even give information about the game itself. [like this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14833/how-can-i-implement-projectile-motion-like-angry-birds), or [this before edit](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/28570/how-to-design-for-play-with-random-player-in-an-online-turn-by-turn-based-game)

In the second example I asked directly for the OP to give reference to the games in a comment. is this appropriate, or should I take different action?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO it really depends. We already discussed [Is “How was entire game X made?” off-topic?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/626/is-how-was-entire-game-x-made-off-topic) And the answer is similar. People asking how game X was made doesnt have any sense, but asking how can implement a feature similar have.

On the second example, the OP wants to implement a Lobby server to link 2 random clients. He just didn't know the name and posted the games as example.

It would be great if someone that understood the problem in these cases go there and edit to precisely say what the OP is wanting to implement.

Comment: So, request further information on the specific feature desired rather then the game itself ( similar to what question 2 already had ), and attempt to disjoint the request from the game it is "similar" to, or taken from?

Comment: Exactly. We actually don't want to know that "game X have feature Y", we want to know the problem the OP is facing. If his problem is discover what technology did the game used, so it is offtopic. But if his problem actually is implementing a system, and the mentioned game was just a example because he cant explain better, so try to "fix" the question.